# Why would this simple MySQL update query take so long?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-update

My host has been sending me messages over the last few months saying that my site is using way too many MySQL minutes.  They also send some logs showing which queries use up the most time on occasion.  Some of the queries are kind of long and complicated, so I understand why they would be an issue.  But a few have me scratching my head.  The one I want to focus on next is this:

```
UPDATE parentmessages SET views=views+1 WHERE parentid='11308'
```

The number is just an example, it could be any parentid.  The parentmessages table has parentid as the primary key, so I would think it would be indexed and easily found.  There are about 11,000 records in the table, which is not really that many.  Here are the numbers my host gave me for how long this query took over 6 instances yesterday:

#### Taking 0.126455 , 1.472929 , 1.638743 , 3.040538 , 7.130041 , 112.498037  seconds to complete

The 112 could be a random glitch I suppose, but why would it take 3, 7 seconds sometimes?!  My best bet is because I have a lot of indices on the table but I don't know enough about MySQL to know if that would matter.  And why would it sometimes be 1/10th of a second and sometimes many seconds?

Here is the show create table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `parentmessages` (
 `parentid` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `level` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `hidden` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `sticky` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `poll` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `topic` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
 `message` varchar(30000) NOT NULL,
 `views` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `replies` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `userid` int(7) NOT NULL,
 `datetimecalc` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `lastreplycalc` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `lastreplyuser` int(7) NOT NULL,
 `editedcalc` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `editeduser` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
 `realediteduser` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
 `altint` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
 `imageurl` varchar(125) DEFAULT NULL,
 `locked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `tempid` int(12) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`parentid`),
 KEY `useridindex` (`userid`),
 KEY `datetimecalcindex` (`datetimecalc`),
 KEY `activeindex` (`active`),
 KEY `lastreplycalcindex` (`lastreplycalc`),
 KEY `levelindex` (`level`),
 KEY `stickyindex` (`sticky`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11716 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be, that another slow query is blocking the table and your update is just waiting for the other query to finish.

Comment: Hmm, if this is the case then I wouldn't really know for sure which the offenders are based on the logs alone?

Comment: That's right. What about the other queries in your "bad queries list"? Are the accessing parentmessages as well?

Comment: The only two others I have addressed so far were these big messy queries that are not particularly important and I didn't have time to streamline so I just took them down for now.  This one, however, is essential to the site and should not be removed, nor do I have any idea how to streamline it considering how simple it is already!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use MyISAM. I forget who said it, maybe PeterZ but "using myisam means you don't care about your data". The easiest way is to check for table locking is to look at the processlist. Dumps, inserts, updates etc will all lock the table. MyISAM is all but deprecated in 5.6 for good reason.